# Callback is fired twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I've been trying to debug this code for awhile to no success...

I have callback on my `Order` object to send a confirmation email email after the Terms of Service have been agreed to. There are 2 ways in which a user could place the order:

1. The user places (`create`) the order and agrees to the Terms of Service on the spot
2. The user places (`create`) the order but waits to agree to the Terms of Service => At some later point the user agrees to the Terms of Service (`update`)

Thus, my callback code looks like this:

```
class Order
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  # for scenario 1
  after_commit :email_alert, on: :create 

  #for scenario 2, executes only if agree_tos is changed because user could update other
  #things about the order WITHOUT agreeing to terms. Also agree_tos_changed? is enough
  #because it will only ever change to true, there's no nil or false option 
  after_save :email_alert, on: :update, if: :agree_tos_changed? 
end
```

`ActiveModel::Dirty` is working fine because I have it elsewhere. Anyway, my current problem is that the `email_alert` is getting triggered twice. But I can't figure out why since the code seems MECE enough to me...

Comment: Is there a reason for this needing to be a callback rather than explicit actions taken closer to the call sites?

Comment: you can try using single line for both create/save callback scenarios `after_commit :email_alert, :if => :persisted?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyway, my current problem is that the email_alert is getting
>   triggered twice.

The only callbacks, that have `on` option are:

- `before_validation`
- `after_commit`

`after_save` does not have this option, thus it is being fired on save (along with `after_commit`).

You can use [`after_update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update), or `before_validation` `on: :update`.

But I would sit and think of a way to make this a single callback, having it `before_validation`, and performing logic **inside** the callback's method.